# Does the AngularUI typeahead plugin allow any typed value?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I have an <input> that uses [Bootstrap typeahead with Angular UI directive](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/).
The display and selection of values in the drop down works fine.

However when I type a value into the input that is not one of the drop down options then this value does not get bound to the model property. Yet what I type remains in the input as if it were valid input.

In the example below, when I type text into the input that is not an option in the autocomplete.referrers array then this text does not get bound to registration.referrer.

Have I configured the input correctly?

```
<input type="text" 
    name="referrer" 
    ng-model="registration.referrer"
    autocomplete="off"
    typeahead="referrer for referrer in autocomplete.referrers | filter:$viewValue"
    />
```

Perhaps the restriction on random text input is by design?

Many thanks if you can answer this.

Comment: that's the way most autocomplete's behave. see jqueryUI, bootstrap etc. Could create a blur directive if needed to clear field if `registration.referrer` is null. Here's a starter for directive: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/H9Fg7OktwZy1lqEH3oPk?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@reggoodwin this is by-design in the current version of the typeahead directive:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/929a46faa3a3eea3dec7ae8c1387f332eee9a9bc/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L110

The rationale behind this behavior is that values from autocomplete should act as reference values. But I was pondering this behavior a bit, it could be made configurable. Feel free to open an issue in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap to discuss more.

Comment: Thanks pkozlowski.opensource for clarifying. I will open an issue as editable selects/combos/autocompletes are useful. Ext JS combo boxes let you edit the field value by default or set the editable property to false to force a selection from the drop down.

Comment: Issue already fixed! Thanks. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/a40c3fbe08fb774ef1e2e6bbe0c00b797f1c71c2.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this directive as an attribute worked for me:

```
<input typeahead-editable="false" >
```